# VBA Range Function/Variable Object error

Tags: vba, excel

I can't figure out why I keep getting an object error in VBA when calling a function with a desired range/variable. I want to call the SumSameCells function from a sub with the B8, B9, B10 as desired/destination cells (rng As Range)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
Sub MySums()

Call SumSameCells(B8)
Call SumSameCells(B9)
Call SumSameCells(B10)

End Sub

Function SumSameCells(rng As Range)

    x = 0
    For i = 2 To 3
        x = x + Sheets(i).Range(" & rng.Address & ")
    Next i
    Sheet1.Range(" & rng.Address & ") = x

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
Call SumSameCells(B8)
```

isn't passing the Range B8 but an undeclared variable named `B8`

Using `Option Explicit` would warn you about this type of error.

This would be simpler:

```
Sub MySums()

SumSameCells "B8"
SumSameCells "B9"
SumSameCells "B10"

End Sub

Function SumSameCells(addr As String)

    x = 0
    For i = 2 To 3
        x = x + Sheets(i).Range(addr).Value
    Next i
    Sheet1.Range(addr) = x

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Variation on the already given answer.

1. Functions return something. You are using a return value so make it a sub.
2. No need for a loop in this case. You can just sum direct.
3. Declare the appropriate type for x. `Option Explicit` has already been mentioned.
4. Use the worksheets collection to avoid trying to work with a chart sheet.
5. Drop the call keyword as is obsolete.

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub MySums()
    SumSameCells "B8"
    SumSameCells "B9"
    SumSameCells "B10"
End Sub

Public Sub SumSameCells(ByVal addr As String)
  Dim x As Double '<== Use whatever appropriate type is
  x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets(2).Range(addr), Worksheets(3).Range(addr))
  Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(addr) = x
End Sub
```